# How to use javascript with multiple elememts having the same id?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ambiguity

I need to manipulate certain elements having some ids using javascript. I do not control the code so unfortunately I cannot rewrite the code with unique ids. For example:

```
<div id="abc">
     <p class="xyz">10</p>
</div>

<div id="abc">
   <p class="xyz">20</p>
</div>
```

The content inside the p tags is guaranteed to be unique. So, I need to perform some operations on the basis of the content inside the p tags.

But if I use DOM to select by id, which of the div would be selected and how do I ensure that I select the required element ?

Comment: It depends how you select the element. By default it will grab the first one it comes across when traversing the DOM

Comment: *"So, I need to perform some operations on the basis of the content inside the p tags."* Can you post some examples how this content is unique and what specific traits of said content you are actually looking for? And I'm assuming that you have unique ids but what you are trying to say is that the ids are useless in you case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, having unique IDs is optimal, however, in the case that it is unavoidable, you can work with it like so:

```js
var abcs = document.querySelectorAll("#abc");

abcs[0].querySelector(".xyz").style.background = "green";

abcs[1].querySelector(".xyz").style.background = "red";
```

```html
<div id="abc">
     <p class="xyz">10</p>
</div>

<div id="abc">
   <p class="xyz">20</p>
</div>
```

Note the use of `document.querySelectorAll()` instead of `document.getElementById()`. That is because `querySelectorAll` will grab all matching elements, whereas `getElementById()` will only grab the first one.

#### More specific to your example:

```js
var abcs = document.querySelectorAll("#abc");


function setAbcByContent(contentValue, color) {
  abcs.forEach(function (elem) {
    if (elem.querySelector(".xyz").innerText === contentValue) {
      elem.style.background = color;
    }
  });
}

setAbcByContent("10", "green");
setAbcByContent("20", "red");
```

```html
<div id="abc">
     <p class="xyz">10</p>
</div>

<div id="abc">
   <p class="xyz">20</p>
</div>
```